# Axios sends custom object with wrong JSON transformation

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a custom class with method `toJSON` and `toString` which declare how transform instance to `JSON` string.

For example

```js
class A {
  constructor(a, b) {
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
  }

  toJSON = () => `${this.a} - ${this.b}`

  toString = () => `${this.a} - ${this.b}`
}
```

But when I send instance of `class A` via `axios` it sends this instance like `"{'a': 'valueA', 'b': 'valueB'}"` instead of string as: `"valueA - valueB"`.

Can I use some custom function inside the class which will be used by `axios` to transform instance to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `instanceOfA.toString()` in the axios call instead of providing `instanceOfA`as the value to sent as JSON  - which axios is sending correctly.

You should probably remove the `toJason`  method of `A` as well - it won't produce valid JSON text in most cases.

Comment: I don't want to call toString by myself because I have an object that I am sending via `axios` and instance of A is a nested part of this object. So I want that toString will be called by axios under the hood.

Comment: It can be any different method (toJSON or etc), it does not matter. The idea is that the axios must call this method ny themself.

Comment: Unfortunately axios will not call any method of an object you send. JSON does not support serializing function properties of objects, it simply ignores them and only serializes non-cycle objects (including arrays) and data properties. Axios will call `JSON.stringify` on the object to be sent to convert it into JSON text, without ever looking at its structure

Comment: You could replace the A object in the parent object being sent with its `toString()` result, but you would need to do this explicitly in code before calling axios.

Comment: I guess I could do it with `axios` under the hood but I guess you're right